How to prove this Proposition about Permutations and cyclic decomposition
I want to prove the following Proposition:

Every permutation $p \in S_n$ can be (uniquly up to order) decomposed
into pairwise disjoint cycles $p_1,...,p_k$, i.e.

Every $k \in [n]$ belongs to exactly one cycle
Every cycle $p_i$ has lenght $\geq 1$.
Two different cycles $p_i$,$p_j$ have no elements in common
$p= p_1 \circ p_2 \circ ... \circ p_k$


Approach:
First, here are the basic definitions I know.
Let $[n]$ denote the set $\{1,2,...,n\}$.
A Permutation $p$ is a bijection $[n] \rightarrow [n]$.
Let $S_n$ denote set of all permutations of $[n]$.
We say $p$ is a cycle (of lenght $k$) if there exists $k$ sucht that
$p^k(i)=i$ and $k$ is the smallest integer with this propery.
Regarding 1:
Let $i \in [n]$ and $p \in S_n$ be arbitrary.
Since $p$ is a bijection $[n] \rightarrow [n]$ one can consider the tuple $(i,p(i),p^2(i),...,p^{n+1}(i))$ which contains $n+1$ elements. Because we have only $n$ distinct numbers but $n+1$ elements in the tuple, by pingenole principle, one number occurs at least two times.
My Problem is that I don't know which number occurs two times.
I dont know how to argue that this happens to $i$. And I don't know
how to argue that $i$ can't belong to another cycle. Thus, my first question is, how does one finish this prove (or how to approach this in a correct way)?
Regarding 2:
This seems trivial, the smalles cycle is a fix point.
Regarding 3:
Let $p_1=(i,p_1(i),...,p_1^{k-1}(i))$ and $p_2=(j,p_2(j),...,p_2^{l-1}(j))$ be two different cycles.
If I understand correctly, I have to show that $S_1:=\{i,p_1(i),...,p_1^{k-1}(i)\}$ and S_2:=$\{j,p_2(j),...,p_2^{l-1}(j)\}$ are disjoint.
Suppose $S_1$ and $S_2$ are not disjoint. This means that there exists
$k'$ and $l'$ such that $p_1^{k'}(i)=p_2^{l'}(j)$.
Maybe some indirect proof would be the way to go here, but I wasn't successful. My second question is, how to continue this prove?
Regarding 4:
The idea here would be similar to what I did in (1):
Let $p \in S_n$,then since $[n]=\{1,2,...,n\}$ has only finite elements we can consider the sequence $1,p(1),p^2(1),...$ and find the smallest $e_1$ such that $p^{e_1}(1)=1$, since e_1 was the smallest exponent, $(1,p(1),...,p^{e_1-1}(1))$ are distinct elements.
Let $X_1:=\{1,p(1),...,p^{e_1-1}(1)\}$ and consider $i:=min [n]\setminus X_1$.
We can do the same argument and find $e_2$ such that $(i,p(i),...,p^{e_2-1}(i))$ is a cycle of lenght $e_2$.
Then let $X_2:=\{i,p(i),...,p^{e_2-1}(i)\}$ and continue this procedere with $([n]\setminus X_1)\setminus X_2$  and so on.
At the end, we get disjoint cycles $p_1,...,p_k$ and since every cycle has a "disjoint domain" from all other cycles we can write them as composition (that commutes).
And my third and last questions is, if my apprach at $4$ is correct?

Note: your definition of a cycle of length $k$ is a bit too broad as it describes any permutation of order $k$, including products of disjoint cycles where the least common multiple of their lengths is $k$. These are the elements that satisfy $p^k = \mathbb{1} \in S_n$ and $p^j \neq 1$ for $0 < j < k$.

For example, using cycle notation, $p = (1,2,3)(4,5,6)$ has order $k=3$ but is not a $3$-cycle; it's a product of two disjoint $3$-cycles. Or for another example, $q = (1,2,3)(4,5)$ has order $\operatorname{lcm}(3, 2) = 6$ and is not a cycle.

Question 1: Why do numbers show up exactly once in a cycle?
You may be overthinking this. It's clear that each element belongs to at least one cycle by the nature of the algorithm that generates the cycles. If a given number in $[n]$ hasn't showed up by iteratively applying $p$ to a previous number, then it gets to start a new cycle. (Of course "start" is a bit of a lie, as every element in a cycle has equal right to consider itself the "starting" number. Nonetheless, the standard algorithm described will generate certain numbers as "first" numbers in cycles.)
But it's also clear that a number cannot show up twice, but this is essentially because $p$ is a bijection. This is expounded upon more clearly in response to your next question.
Question 2: Why do cycles partition the set $[n]$?
Regarding your stub of a proof of part 3, note that the both the functions $p_1$ and $p_2$ that you apply iteratively to generate the two cycles are actually just $p$. So if the cycles aren't disjoint, then there's some $k'$ and $l'$ such that
$$
\def\r#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\g#1{\color{green}{#1}}
\def\b#1{\color{blue}{#1}}
p^{k'}(i) = p^{l'}(j). 
$$
This is enough to show that the cycles are identical simply by applying $p$ enough times. To be more explicit, since $i$ is a member of a $k$-cycle, and $0 \leq k' < k$, the complementary exponent $k'' = k - k'$ satisfies $0 < k'' \leq k$ and
$$
i = p^k(i) = p^{k''} \circ p^{k'}(i) 
= p^{k''} \circ p^{l'}(j) = p^{k'' + l'}(j) 
$$
Now, we can reduce $k'' + l'$ modulo $l$ if we like, but it doesn't matter. The upshot is that $i$ is in the cycle starting at $j$. By applying $p$ up to $k-1$ times, this shows that the entire cycle beginning with $i$ lies in the cycle beginning with $j$. Explicitly, let $l'' = k'' + l' = k - k' + l'$, so
$$
\bigl(i, p(i), p^2(i), \dots, p^{k-1}(i)\bigr) 
= \bigl(p^{l''}(j), p^{l''+1}(j), p^{l''+2}(j), \dots, p^{l''+k-1}(j)\bigr), 
$$
where again the powers can be reduced modulo $l$ if we like. This shows set containment in one direction, and actually something stronger. Since one more application of $p$ returns to $i$, we may conclude that the cycle involving $j$ also has an order that divides $k$.
An analogous argument with the roles of $i$ and $j$ reversed shows that the cycle involving $j$ is also a subset of that involving $i$ and that it's order divides $l$. But this means that $k = l$ and the two cycles are identical.
Question 3: Why can we reconstruct $p$ as a composition of its disjoint cycles?
Your answer is fine.

An example:
Here's what this looks like for the permutation
$$
p = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
5 & 8 & 3 & 7 & 6 & 1 & 4 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
in two-line notation. This is shorthand for stating that $p(1) = 5$, $p(2) = 8$, etc.
Start with $1$:
$$
1 \mapsto 5 \mapsto 6 \mapsto 1, 
$$
so $(1\,5\,6)$ is the $3$-cycle that permutes those three elements.
Now begin with $2 \notin \{1, 5, 6\}$:
$$
2 \mapsto 8 \mapsto 2, 
$$
so $(2\,8)$ is the two $2$-cycle (a.k.a. transposition) that swaps those two elements.
Next, $3 \notin \{1, 5, 6\} \cup \{2, 8\}$: notice that $3$ is a fixed point, hence in its own $1$-cycle $(3)$.
Finally, start with $4 \notin \{1, 5, 6\} \cup \{2, 8\} \cup \{3\}$:
$$
4 \mapsto 7 \mapsto 4, 
$$
producing another transposition $(4\,7)$.
Thus, $p = (1\,5\,6)(2\,8)(3)(4\,7)$, and the order of this composition actually doesn't matter as they individual cycles are each pairwise disjoint. Note that usually fixed points are suppressed in cycle notation, so we would write $p = (1\,5\,6)(2\,8)(4\,7)$.
Note: analogous to what's mentioned in the comments, since $\operatorname{lcm}(3, 2, 2, 1) = 6$, this permutation has order $6$, but it is certainly not a $6$-cycle!
Here are the successive powers of $p$ applied to $[8]$, so each row is $p$ applied to the row above it. The elements are colored according to their cycles according to $\r{(1\,5\,6)}\b{(2\,8)}(3)\g{(4\,7)}$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
[8] \\
p([8]) \\
p^2([8]) \\
p^3([8]) \\
p^4([8]) \\
p^5([8]) \\
p^6([8]) 
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
\r1 & \b2 & 3 & \g4 & \r5 & \r6 & \g7 & \b8 \\
\r5 & \b8 & 3 & \g7 & \r6 & \r1 & \g4 & \b2 \\
\r6 & \b2 & 3 & \g4 & \r1 & \r5 & \g7 & \b8 \\
\r1 & \b8 & 3 & \g7 & \r5 & \r6 & \g4 & \b2 \\
\r5 & \b2 & 3 & \g4 & \r6 & \r1 & \g7 & \b8 \\
\r6 & \b8 & 3 & \g7 & \r1 & \r5 & \g4 & \b2 \\
\r1 & \b2 & 3 & \g4 & \r5 & \r6 & \g7 & \b8 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
As you can see, every $3$ applications of $p$ returns the $3$-cycle to its original order, and every $2$ applications of $p$ returns the $2$-cycles to their original order.

Thank you very much!
